# Converting a list into a matrix by diagonally filling up the elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, range

I have a `sorted list` which looks as below:

```
mylist = [-2, -2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

The list is sorted in ascending order based upon the number of times it appears. In case of a tie, the list is sorted based upon the values.

I need to convert this list into a `square matrix of equal chunks(3*3 in this case)` such that the numbers are placed `"diagonally" starting from the bottom right corner`.

The general case is to divide the list in equal chunks.

> Desired Output:

```
res = [[3, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 1],
      [1, -2, -2]]
```

I have written the below code but still not able to get the desired output:

```
def create_matrix(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        print(i)
        yield lst[i: i+n]

m = create_matrix(mylist, 3)

print(list(m))
```

**One solution could be to place pairs in queue/stack and then pop as needed.**

Comment: One suggestion: using the numbers 1 through 9 would make it extremely obvious how the numbers are placed here. Using repeating numbers makes it unobvious what direction many of the numbers are being added in. Obviously, we can just read the text explaining how the numbers are added, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using an example. Maybe I'm just being picky though.

Comment: Is it always 3×3? If not, what's the general case?

Comment: The general case is to divide the list in equal chunks

Comment: It would be less ambiguous to use unique numbers in the input...

Comment: I have to use the given list and cannot change it. `mylist = [-2, -2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: Sure but you could provide another non ambiguous example. That doesn't prevent you from using whatever list later... Otherwise just hardcore `res` and problem solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to iterate the output matrix this way (NxN = 5x5 example, 0->24 order):

```
[[ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10],
 [ 2,  4,  7, 11, 15],
 [ 5,  8, 12, 16, 19],
 [ 9, 13, 17, 20, 22],
 [14, 18, 21, 23, 24]]
```

For each cell, the coordinates (i,j) have their sum equal to the number of the diagonal (`k`) from top-left to bottom right (2*N-1 diagonals in total)

For the N first diagonals, the first item has `i=0`, the following ones `i=k-N` where `k` is the diagonal number.

The last item has `i=k` with a maximum of `N`.

`j = k-i`

This gives us the following algorithm to iterate the cells in order:

```
import math

mylist = [-2, -2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]

N = int(math.sqrt(len(mylist))) # 3

out = [[None for _ in range(N)]
       for _ in range(N)]

r = reversed(mylist)

for k in range(2*N-1):
    start = 0 if k<N else k-N+1
    stop = min(k, N-1)
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        out[i][k-i] = next(r)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 1],
 [1, -2, -2]]
```

### alternative approach

If you want to tackle the problem the other way around and generate the items in order of the rows, then columns, you can use a generator:

```
def yield_diag(lst, N):
    for I in range(N):
        # sum of successive diagonal lengths
        i = I*(I+1)//2
        j = 0
        for J in range(I, N+I):
            # step between columns
            j += min(J, N)-max(0, J-N+1)
            yield lst[i+j]

# 5x5 example
list(yield_diag(list(range(25)), 5))
# [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 4, 7, 11, 15, 5, 8, 12, 16, 19, 9, 13, 17, 20, 22, 14, 18, 21, 23, 24]
```

OP example:

```
list(yield_diag(mylist[::-1], 3))

# [3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, -2, -2]
```

As 2D:

```
N = 3

it = yield_diag(mylist[::-1], N)

[[next(it) for _ in range(N)]
 for _ in range(N)]
```

Output:

```
[[3, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 1],
 [1, -2, -2]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid doing the `r = reversed(mylist)? and start filling from bottom right?`                                                        
  Right now it is taking >50ms

Comment: What do you think? (The answer is yes). In the first approach the calculation of the position is direct, how would you inverse the order? In the second one knowing the list length and the position to index, how could you get the mirror elements?

Comment: I am able to achieve it by changing last line to `out[i][k-i] = mylist.pop()` and removing the `r = reversed(mylist)`. Thanks for all you explanation. Very helpful

Comment: You could have just inverted the ranges ;)

Comment: oh okay. can you please update your answer to invert the ranges? That seems to be a better approach.

Comment: Use `for k in range(2*N-2, 0, -1)` and `for i in range(stop, start-1, -1)`. And use `r = iter(mylist)` (or increment an indexer yourself)

Comment: Is this for an assignment? Or an online game? You should maybe revise your python basics ;)

Comment: This is for an assignment. Agree :)

Comment: @meallhour >50ms?! Even with any ridiculously inefficient code that isn't of a stupid exponential complexity and doesn't access another computer, it should take less than that.

Comment: It depends how many items you have. With several thousands/millions it probably takes around that time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to wrap a list backwards up a matrix, which seems to solve this case. Also, your question doesn't make any sense. Diagonally? And how is that list sorted?

```
def create_matrix(lst, n):
    ret = [[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n*n-1,-1,-1):
        ret[i//n][i%n] = lst[n*n-1-i]
    return ret
```

Edit: That doesn't work. I don't think anyone knows what you mean by diagonally.

Comment: The list is sorted in ascending order based upon the number of times it appears. In case of a tie, the list is sorted based upon the values.

Comment: Getting an error" `IndexError: list index out of range`